# I want to show a error message to the user if his comment is too short

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm doing a feature to my boss website, that is, if a person writes down a comments that has less than 5 words I would show him an error message saying

> 1 error prohibited your comment from being saved *comment is too short (minimum 5 characthers).

I do not have much experience with rails nor ruby, but my boss asked me to do that so.

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <%= form_for([ @article, @article.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :commenter %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :body %><br>
      <%= form.text_area :body %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your model (`comment.rb`?):
`validates :text, length: { minimum: 5 }` (change `:text` to name of field that should be validated)

Download https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/blob/master/lib/generators/nifty/layout/templates/error_messages_helper.rb or https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/blob/master/lib/generators/nifty/layout/templates/error_messages_helper.rb into your project (into `app/helpers` directory).

Add `<%= f.error_messages %>` into your template (below `<%= form_for ... do |f| %>`)

More information about validation:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length

http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3?view=asciicast

Comment: You don't need to download nifty generators, you can just add the message there itself like: 
  `validates :body, length: { minimum: 8,
    too_short: "Minimum 8 characters needed, you have: %{count}" }`